# How to keep the data in $group?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

Here is data of the aggregate. I want to add a stage to group all the data has the same _id (datetime), but have to check the type to set the name exactly, If type is temperature, we have add temperature before the property name to identify which field is temperutre

```
[{
    "_id" : "2021-05-23T00:00",
    "type" : "humidity",
    "level_1_avg" : null,
    "level_1_min" : "80.0",
    "level_1_max" : "80.0"
},
{
    "_id" : "2021-05-23T00:00",
    "type" : "temperature",
    "level_1_avg" : 14.25,
    "level_1_min" : NumberLong(-10),
    "level_1_max" : NumberLong(34)
},
{
    "_id" : "2021-05-23T01:00",
    "type" : "temperature",
    "level_1_avg" : 30.3333333333333,
    "level_1_min" : NumberLong(24),
    "level_1_max" : NumberLong(37)
},
{
    "_id" : "2021-05-23T01:00",
    "type" : "humidity",
    "level_1_avg" : null,
    "level_1_min" : "80.0",
    "level_1_max" : "80.0"
}]
```

The result expected:

```
[{
  _id: "2021-05-23T00:00",
  "humidity_level_1_avg" : null,
  "humidity_level_1_min" : "80.0",
  "humidity_level_1_max" : "80.0",
  "temperature_level_1_avg" : 14.25,
  "temperature_level_1_min" : NumberLong(-10),
  "temperature_level_1_max" : NumberLong(34)
}, {
  "_id" : "2021-05-23T01:00",
  "humidity_level_1_avg" : 30.3333333333333,
  "humidity_level_1_min" : NumberLong(24),
  "humidity_level_1_max" : NumberLong(37),
  "temperature_level_1_avg" : null,
  "temperature_level_1_min" : "80.0",
  "temperature_level_1_max" : "80.0"
}]
```

Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

See if the below query is what you are looking for.

Let me know if you need an explanation of every stage and operators used.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "values": {
        "$push": {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$let": {
              "vars": {
                "elemType": "$$ROOT.type"
              },
              "in": {
                "$map": {
                  "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": {
                        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
                      },
                      "cond": {
                        "$not": {
                          "$in": [
                            "$$this.k",
                            [
                              "_id",
                              "id",
                              "type"
                            ]
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    },
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "k": {
                      "$concat": [
                        "$$elemType",
                        "_",
                        "$$this.k"
                      ]
                    },
                    "v": "$$this.v"
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },    
        }
      }
    },
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "_id": "$_id"
          },
          {
            "$reduce": {
              "input": "$values",
              "initialValue": {},
              "in": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$this",
                  "$$value"
                ]
              }
            },
          },
        ]
      }
    },
  },
])
```

[Mongo Playground Sample Execution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QUJQc2CHR1N)